# How to read file from angular post in web api?

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, owin

I successfully implemented the OWIN based token authentication.

But before implementing this, when I try to get posted files multipart form data from my angular app to web api by using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[i].FileName`, then it easily gives me posted file that I want.

But after implementing owin based token authentication I am unable to get posted file and an error occurs on same line.

By spending more days on this error I have found most of the answers from internet but I still can't solve my problem.

And most of the solutions offered say that you cannot access `HttpContext.Current.Request` in a self-hosted container like

```
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

I am really stuck on this, so please help me.

The error is:

> The line 306 is : HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[i].FileName
>
> An error has occurred.
>   ExceptionMessage: This method or
>   property is not supported after HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream
>   has been invoked.
>   ExceptionType: System.Web.HttpException
>   StackTrace
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureFiles()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Files()
>   at Nullplex.Rest.Controllers.UserBasicController.UpdateUserBasicByID(UserBasic
>   UserBasic) in d:\BitBucket\PayBackRestApp
>   \Nullplex.Rest\Controllers\UserBasicController.cs:line 306
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.c__DisplayClass10
>   .b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor
>   .ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor
>   .ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary2
>   arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
>
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>
> at System.Runtime .CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices
>   .TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices .TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n at System.Runtime
>   .CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n at System.Runtime
>   .CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult. d__2.MoveNext()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read file posted from angular in web api like this

```
if (!this.Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
{
    var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    await this.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    var content = provider.Contents.First();
    var buffer = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

now buffer contains the file data as `byte[]`

Comment: Thank you.
By looking at your code I got byte array then I converted into Image by using System.Drawing and saved with Image.Save(''FileName",ImageFormat);